I get an error when i run a program using tkinter
When i try running the most basic program with tkinter, it says name 'Tk' is not defined. And i can't seem to find a solution. Btw, i'm using python 3.12
Here is the program:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.mainloop()

Tried to get a window, got an error instead.
error traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\benyb\OneDrive\Desktop\Documentes\Python\appelsienscreen.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
  File "c:\Users\benyb\OneDrive\Desktop\Documentes\Python\tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
    root = Tk()
           ^^
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined


Please update your question with the full error traceback.

@quamrana I have added the full error

Your error shows something different from the code you posted. I would copy back the code you posted and run that instead.

You can't have a tkinter.py file here. Rename or move it.

You can't have a python file named same as a module name, try renaming the file.
